# Script fails to execute following prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, web

I'm trying to execute a jQuery script but I'm encountering problems when certain segments are added to the script. For example, the script below works:

```
var cNum = 16;

var clickButton = function(opt){

    cNum = prompt('Select a number from 1 to 128');
    makeGrid(cNum);

};
```

... and calls a prompt as it's supposed to. However, adding a function for makeGrid results in the script not being executed at all:

var cNum = 16;

```
var clickButton = function(opt){

    cNum = prompt('Select a number from 1 to 128');
    makeGrid(cNum);

};

var makeGrid = function(opt){
    if (opt >= 1 && <= 128) {
        alert("Inconsequential text");
    } 
    else { 
        alert("Inconsequential text");
    }
};
```

The alerts above are just an example of how the script fails to execute.

Comment: Look in the JavaScript error console and tell what errors you see there.

Comment: how about if you define the function better: `function makeGrid(opt) {...};` instead of having the var..

Comment: @JFit Won't make any difference.

Comment: also if you make a jsfiddle.net you may spot the problem yourself.. or it'll aid us in helping.

Comment: @Juhana Thanks.. Unaware of why functions are declared that way sometimes.. personally I would always just `function name(...);` Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry - I spot your problem now.. its <= 128 has no opts.. so you're comparing it to nothing..
try:

```
var cNum = 16;

var clickButton = function(opt){

    cNum = prompt('Select a number from 1 to 128');
    makeGrid(cNum);

};

var makeGrid = function(opt){
    if (opt >= 1 && opt <= 128) {
        alert("Inconsequential text");
    } 
    else { 
        alert("Inconsequential text");
    }
};
```

Here is a fiddle the way i'd do it:

**http://jsfiddle.net/uvLsuk2k/**